# RSME on dataframe of multiple files in R

Tags: r, split, sapply

My goal is to read many files into R, and ultimately, run a Root Mean Square Error (`rmse`) function on each pair of columns within each file.
I have this code:

```
    #This calls all the files into a dataframe
filnames <- dir("~/Desktop/LGsampleHUCsWgraphs/testRSMEs", pattern = "*_45Fall_*")
    #This reads each file
read_data <- function(z){
       dat <- read_excel(z, skip = 0, ) 
       return(dat)
    }
    #This combines them into one list and splits them by the names in the first column
datalist <- lapply(filnames, read_data)
    bigdata <- rbindlist(datalist, use.names = T)
    splitByHUCs <- split(bigdata, f = bigdata$HUC...1 , sep = "\n", lex.order = TRUE)
```

So far, all is working well. Now I want to apply an `rmse` *[library(Metrics)]* analysis on each of the "splits" created above. I don't know what to call the "splits". Here I have used *names* but that is an R reserved word and won't work. I tried the *bigdata* object but that didn't work either. I also tried to use *splitByHUCs*, and *rMSEs*.

```
rMSEs <- sapply(splitByHUCs, function(x) rmse(names$Predicted, names$Actual)) 
write.csv(rMSEs, file = "~/Desktop/testRMSEs.csv")
```

The `rmse` code works fine when I run it on a single file and create a name for the dataframe:

```
read_excel("bcc1_45Fall_1010002.xlsm")
bcc1F1010002 <- read_excel("bcc1_45Fall_1010002.xlsm")
rmse(bcc1F1010002$Predicted, bcc1F1010002$Actual)
```

The "splits" are named by the "*splitByHUCs*" script, like this:[image: sample of split results]

They are named for the file they came from, appropriately. I need some kind of reference name for the `rmse` formula and I don't know what it would be. Any ideas? Thanks. I made some small versions of the files, but I don't know how to add them here.

Comment: Try `sapply(splitByHUCs, function(x) rmse(x$Predicted, x$Actual))`. Based on the image showed, `splitByHUCs` is a list of data.frame.  When you loop over the `list` with `sapply` and specify the lambda function, the `x` is each of the elements of the `list` i.e. individual data.frame.  Therefore, extract the columns with `$` and apply the `rmse`

Comment: That was it! How do I give you credit for answering?

Comment: I posted as a soluiton.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is a `list`, we can loop over the `list` with `sapply/lapply` as in the OP's code, but the `names$` is incorrect as the lambda function object is `x` which signifies each of the elements of the `list` (i.e. a data.frame).  Therefore, instead of `names$`, use `x$`

```
sapply(splitByHUCs, function(x) rmse(x$Predicted, x$Actual))
```

Comment: Getting an explanation (as you did both times) instead of just a piece of code is always invaluable. Teaching the man to fish rather than just handing him a fish.